# Is it possible to train Rhinomocks for arbitrary input?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, rhino-mocks

I am trying to set up a unit test for a piece of code that uses a spelling corrector.  I have the code properly dependency injected, so setting up the stub in Rhinomocks is not a problem, but the block of text I've created for the test is a good 50 words long and I would really rather not have 50 lines of code that look something like this:

```
spellingCorrector.Stub(x => x.CorrectWord("the")).Return("the");
spellingCorrector.Stub(x => x.CorrectWord("boy")).Return("boy");
spellingCorrector.Stub(x => x.CorrectWord("ran")).Return("ran");
```

For the purposes of my unit tests I think assuming that the words are spelled right is okay.  Is there a way to get Rhinomocks to simply follow a rule about returning, something to the effect of:

```
spellingCorrector.Stub(x => x.CorrectWord(y)).Return(y);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `IgnoreArguments()` method:

```
spellingCorrector
    .Stub(x => x.CorrectWord(null))
    .IgnoreArguments()
    .Return(y);
```

This way no matter what value is passed to the `CorrectWord` method, it will return `y`.

---

UPDATE:

After your comment it is more clear:

```
Func<string, string> captureArg = arg => arg;
spellingCorrector.Stub(x => x.CorrectWord(null)).IgnoreArguments().Do(captureArg);
```

This will use whatever value is passed as argument as return value. Adapt the `captureArg` delegate if you need to perform some transformations on this return value.

Comment: Close, but not quite what I need.  I need it to return what was put in, not the same thing every time.

Answer (score 0):

For anything complex like this, instead of using RhinoMocks, write your own little stub class. I'd back it with a Dictionary of all the words that should be corrected, and return the word if it isn't in the Dictionary.

Mocks were only created to make this kind of thing easier. If it isn't easier (or more importantly, more readable) to use mocks, just write the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not particularly attached to Rhinomock, you can use [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart):

```
spellingCorrector.Setup(x => x.CorrectWord(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(x => x);
```